# line of lights across sky

Tags: amateur-observing

This morning at 6AM I saw a line of lights coming out of Orion, moving across the North star then Big Dipper and disappearing into the early dawn.  I saw at least 30, no idea how many came before I noticed them.  They were not all evenly spaced, all moving at the same speed, very high, no sound. If these are Musk's satellites, why are they still sort of stacked, why are they moving in a NNE direction, and can I expect to see them again?

Comment: I had a similar experience. Turned out to be a group of migrating geese flying at a height where only their underbellies were lit by the city lights! The partial V shape gave it away!

Comment: I would recommend googling "starlink satellite groups observation" to find out if you were looking in the right place at the right time :-)

Comment: BTW, you need to post your location (Lat and Long) for us to consider this an astronomical vs. local (birds, etc) event.